# How to index n-dims tensor with (n-k)-dims tensor in TF?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a `tensor A` with shape `[7, 7, 2, 4]` and a `tensor B` with shape `[7, 7]`.

`Tensor B` is the `argmax` of `tensor A` and its value is `0,1`.

I want to get `tensor C` with shape `[7, 7, 4]` or `[7, 7, 1, 4]` from A and B.

The rule is the *(i, j)* element of `tensor B` is the index of the 2-nd dimensions of `tensor A`.

How can I do it quickly? I tried to get C by `A[B]` but it doesn't work. Can any one help me? Thank you.

Comment: Could you include samples from your code?

Comment: @corvusMidnight I just try to implement YOLOv1 so the source code is quite big, I can't post it here. I fixed that. Thank u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I was used [tf.gather_nd](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gather_nd) to solve this problem:

```
tensor_C = tf.gather_nd(tensor_A, tf.expand_dims(tf.argmax(tensor_B, 2), 2), batch_dims=3)
```